# Optimize pipeline query in mongodb 3.2

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a sample mongodb data for Mongodb 3.2 below and want to optimize pipeline:

```
{"_id": {"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747f8"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test6","revenue":10.0,"unitsSold":1,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747f9"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test1","revenue":11.0,"unitsSold":2,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fa"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test2","revenue":12.0,"unitsSold":3,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fb"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test3","revenue":13.0,"unitsSold":4,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fc"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test4","revenue":14.0,"unitsSold":5,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fd"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test5","revenue":15.0,"unitsSold":6,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fe"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test10","revenue":16.0,"unitsSold":7,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747ff"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test11","revenue":100.0,"unitsSold":100,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e462"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test1","revenue":20.0,"unitsSold":10,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e463"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test2","revenue":19.0,"unitsSold":9,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e464"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test3","revenue":18.0,"unitsSold":8,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e465"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test4","revenue":17.0,"unitsSold":7,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e466"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test5","revenue":16.0,"unitsSold":6,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e467"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test1","revenue":15.0,"unitsSold":5,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e468"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test2","revenue":14.0,"unitsSold":4,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e469"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test3","revenue":13.0,"unitsSold":3,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e46a"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test4","revenue":12.0,"unitsSold":2,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e46b"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test5","revenue":11.0,"unitsSold":1,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
```

I have the following query :

```
 db.books.aggregate([
{$match:{'bookCategory.categoryCode' : 'Cooking/'}},
 {$unwind:'$bookCategory'}, 
/* This unwind creating performance problems, with 1M records, with 100 (Book Categories / book)  elements in subdocuments causes 100M documents to be retrieved, may cause memory problems for our memory size : 4GB */
 /*Pipeline 1 */
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "categoryCode": "$bookCategory.categoryCode",
        "book": "$bookName"
    },
    "revenue": { $sum:"$revenue" },
     "unitsSold": { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
}
 }
,
{$match:{'_id.categoryCode' : {$regex : 'Cooking/'}}},
 /*Pipeline 2 */
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.categoryCode",


    "books": {
        "$push": {
          //  "category": "$_id.categoryCode",
    "book":"$_id.book",
    "revenue": { $sum:"$revenue" },
     "unitsSold": { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
        },
    },
    "topRevenue": { $sum: "$revenue" },
    "topUnitsSold": { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
}},
{ "$sort": { "topRevenue": -1 } },
{ "$limit": 3},

{ "$project": {
    "books": { "$slice": [ "$books", 3 ] },
    "topRevenue": 1,
    "topUnitsSold": 1
}}

])
```

When executed Pipeline 1 , it generates 48 documents, the following output :

/* 1 */

```
{
"_id" : {
    "categoryCode" : "Food Receipe/Taste",
    "book" : "Test1"
},
"revenue" : 11,
"unitsSold" : 2
```

}

```
/* 2 */

{
"_id" : {
    "categoryCode" : "Cooking",
    "book" : "Test6"
},
"revenue" : 10,
"unitsSold" : 1
```

}

```
/* 3 */
{
"_id" : {
    "categoryCode" : "Food Receipe/Taste",
    "book" : "Test2"
},
"revenue" : 12,
"unitsSold" : 3
```

}

```
 /* 4 */
{
"_id" : {
    "categoryCode" : "Food Receipe/Taste",
    "book" : "Test6"
},
"revenue" : 10,
"unitsSold" : 1
```

}
     ...........................and so on

I want to solve this in pipeline 1 stage only. Please lemme know whether is  possible with mongodb 3.2.   Please lemme know whether is possible with spring-data-mongodb.

Please help

Regards

Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the match in the first stage keep it there, then i would suggest you put as little data as possible through the pipeline, so after the match add a project.

1. Include only the fields you need.
2. Include only the relevant array items, so the unwind generated "lesser" documents

For the second you can use [array $filter operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). Which is something like :

```
$project: {
         bookCategory: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$bookCategory",
               as: "bookCat",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$bookCat.categoryCode", "Cooking/"] }
            }
         }
      }
```

This should reduce the number of documents and make the aggregation more performant.

You could even eliminate the first match, because the projection eliminates the array items not maching the $eq statement.

Just try some combinations and see what works (and is the most performant) in your scenario

UPDATE:
i created a little aggregation, with an Array filter to limit the number of items in your array (and so the unwind).
This groups the books on Category. I put the book document in the books array (for reference) but you can limit this to only the title (lesser data, faster the aggregation).

```
db.collection.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $project: {
        bookName : 1,
        revenue : 1,
        unitsSold : 1,
      bookCategory: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$bookCategory",
                     as: "bookCat",
                     cond: { $eq:[ 'Cooking', {$substr:["$$bookCat.categoryCode",0,7]}] }
                  }
               }
      }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $unwind: "$bookCategory"
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
      $group: {
         _id: {
              categoryCode: "$bookCategory.categoryCode",
          },
          books : { $push: "$$ROOT" },
          revenue: { $sum:"$revenue" },
          unitsSold: { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
      }
    }

  ]
);
```

I asume you create this aggregation in code so you can build the arrayfilter depending on the value you want (Food / Cooking)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HoefMeistert,  Please see my data some book belongs to categories  "Cooking/","Cooking/Beverages/Bartending", "Cooking/Beverages","Food Receipe/","Food Receipe/Bartending" and other books belongs to categories "Cooking/","Cooking/Beverages/Bartending", "Cooking/Beverages","Food Receipe/","Food Receipe/Bartending" and "Food Receipe/Bartending/Taste". When I try to match w.r.t. "Cooking/" category in the first pipeline its retrieving records for Cooking and Food Receipe categories. Please help

Comment: @chiku i saw your data. Would be nice to test $redact followed by $match (https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) "$redact + $match Sequence Optimization". Even more, $regex could be replaced by $substr maybe (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)?

Comment: @chiku What are you trying to do with the match on "Cooking/". Are you always matching on the first part? Or could you also do a match on "Bartending"? If so i advise you to reorder your stages.

Comment: @HoefMeistert, I want to calculate revenue and unitssold and total revenue, total unitssold, for all the books belonging  all matches starting with 'Cooking/' category, group by their book categories like 'Cooking/Beverages' , 'Cooking/Beverages/Bartending' etc.The query I matched was with 'Cooking/' category, and pipelined to regex of 'Cooking/' category, I don't want to unwind because of performance problems, if we have 1M docs and 100 categories of Cooking category, the first pipeline unwinds about 100M docs. hope u understand the severity. Please help. kris

Comment: @HoefMeistert, Any help please on this issue. regards, kris

Comment: @chiku Yes i understand your issue. But you want to do variuos calculations so you really need to unwind :|. Do you think you get performance issues or do you really have them? Because all operations are on the server and the results after the last stage are presented. Don't you have some kind of "dummy" set then i can do some tests

Comment: @HoefMeistert thanks for your reply, the topRevenue, topUnitsSold can be left out, I can do with application code,Please help WITHOUT unwind pipeline and WITH pagination of bookName (limiting to 3) per bookCategory.bookCode.Regards, kris

Comment: @chiku I don't understand, could you specify what result you want?

Comment: @chiku added a aggregation with an arrayfilter check it out.

Comment: Thanks a ton @HoefMeistert , regards, kris

Comment: @HoefMeistert can you help me write the same query with spring-data-mongodb 1.x / mongo-java 2.x /mongo-java 3.x  framework. Regards, kris

Comment: @chiku I'm not really into spring-data, but i guess you are strugeling with the $filter, there was an issue in Spring-data, this should be resolved, check [out this article](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1492). unwind and group are handled in [the normal documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation). When still strugling, give me a sign and i will try to supply an example